# How to grant edit rights to a moderator in an openldap server?

Tags: openldap, slapd

I´m having trouble with ldapmodify . What I´m trying to do is to grant access to a subtree of my directory to a specific useraccount.

Here is my LDIF file:

```
access to dn.subtree="ou=people,ou=orgaunit,dc=home,dc=arpa"
        by dn="uid=ldap-people,ou=users,ou=orgaunit,dc=home,dc=arpa" write
        by * read
```

When I call `ldapmodify -x -W -D "cn=admin,dc=home,dc=arpa" -f my.ldif` I get the following error:

```
ldapmodify: invalid format (line 1) entry: ""
```

I used an example from [the official documentation](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin25/access-control.html#Introduction) as the base for my LDIF file.

I´m working on Debian Linux 12

```
uname -a
Linux dtpl 6.1.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.38-4 (2023-08-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
slapd -V
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.5.13+dfsg-5 (Feb  8 2023 01:56:12) $
```

I tried to use ldapadd because it´s a new rule. I get the same error message as above.
I also checked with the file command if the line endings were correct:

```
my.ldif: ASCII text
```

What could be wrong with my file?